# getting the Unique DeviceId in Windows Phone 8.1 using C++ code

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, uniqueidentifier, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get unique 44 digits device id of windows phone 8.1 using c++ code. I've followed the following link for it.

http://abundantcode.com/alternate-way-of-getting-the-unique-deviceid-in-windows-phone-8/#comment-85511

It's a short code of one line only,

```
var UniqueID = Windows.Phone.System.Analytics.HostInformation.PublisherHostId;
```

but I'm getting a lot of errors on it.

```
error C3083: 'Analytics': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type , 
error C3083: 'HostInformation': the symbol to the left of a '::'must be a `type  ,`
error C2039: 'PublisherHostId' : is not a member of'Windows::Phone::System'  ,  
error C2065: 'PublisherHostId' : undeclared identifier
```

I've also defines `ID_CAP_IDENTIY_DEVICE` property which is mentioned here in this way.

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
```

Although I'm confused about it that it's right or wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're building Windows Phone 8.0 C++? This compiles fine for me: `auto x = Windows::Phone::System::Analytics::HostInformation::PublisherHostId;`

Comment: O Sorry! It's Windows Phone 8.1 and yes I'm doing it in c++.

Comment: OK please update the title and the tags then :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows Phone 8.0, you can use `PublisherHostId`, but for Windows Phone 8.1 native code projects you need to use [`HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken(v=win.10).aspx) aka the **ASHWID**.

This is so you can more easily share code with Windows 8.1. This ID is constant for a given app on a given device, but will vary across apps and across devices.

Here's a sample that works in Windows Phone 8.1:

```
using namespace Windows::System::Profile;
using namespace Windows::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace Platform;

auto token = HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken(nullptr);
Array<byte>^ buffer = ref new Array<byte>(token->Id->Length);

// Nothing to do with crypto; just a helpful class 
// to convert IBuffer^ -> Array^
CryptographicBuffer::CopyToByteArray(token->Id, &buffer);

// Output the first four bytes of the key
char key[9];
sprintf_s(key, sizeof(key) / sizeof(key[0]), "%02X%02X%02X%02X", 
  buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
OutputDebugStringA(key);
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter, I'm going to try it.

Comment: I've used  `HardwareToken^ packageSpecificToken;
packageSpecificToken =  Windows::System::Profile::HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken(nonce);` but it's giving me undefined identifier error for **HardwareToken** and **nonce**.

Comment: Added sample with null nonce

Comment: It's working perfectly but I wonder it's size is 31 instead of 44, are both same?

Comment: No they aren't the same. One is shared per-publisher, the other is per-App